# set/getAttribute comparisons only work with strings?

Tags: javascript, html, boolean, setattribute, getattribute

I would like to set a `span` node's `visited` attribute to `true` or `false` based on if it has been visited.

```
test();

function test () {

    var el = document.createElement("span");
    el.setAttribute("visited", false);

    el.setAttribute("visited", true);

    alert(el.getAttribute("visited") === true); //False
    alert(el.getAttribute("visited") === "true"); //True

}
```

I initially set the attribute "visited" to boolean *false*, then set the boolean to *true*. I noticed that when I checked if the attribute was `true`, it returned false, but if I checked the string `true`, it returned true.

The [MSN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) only talk about the attributeName as needing to be string, not the value. So why doesn't comparing against bools work?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g1nad5L0/)

Comment: Yes, `attributes` are always strings, but `properties` can be several different types.

Comment: MSDN isn't a normative reference for the relevant standard, the W3C is: [*setAttribute*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082),  [*getAttribute*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `getAttribute` return type is `string` not `bool`

Return Value:   **A String, representing the specified attribute's value**.

> Note: If the attribute does not exist, the return value is null or an
> empty string ("")

Answer (score 1):

The `===` operator checks both value and type (with no implicit coercion of types).

Since `getAttribute` returns a string value, the comparison is only `true` when compared to the string "true" and not when compared to the boolean value of `true`.

To put it another way, when using the `===` operator...

```
true === 'true' // false
'true' === 'true' // true
true === true // true
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the definition of attributes as defined by the HTML standard:

> [**3.2.3.1 Attributes**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attributes)
>
> Except where otherwise specified, attributes on [HTML elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#html-elements) may have
>   any string value, including the empty string. Except where explicitly
>   stated, there is no restriction on what text can be specified in such
>   attributes.

So, to repeat what was already stated, HTML attributes are always strings.

Comment: 'may have' is not the same as 'shall have' - your interpretation of 'are alwasys strings` is not correct.  Also, as you quote, there are some exceptions.

Comment: I'm interpreting it in such a way that "may have" relates to "any", not to the type, as further explained in the second sentence.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes it does, but ochi means that *"may have any string value"* does not mean *"only has string values"*. The above text does say it can have any string value, it does not say attributes must be strings.

Comment: @Spencer: Sure, but if this is not implied, why are "string values" called out explicitly? Why is there no mention of number values or list values, etc?

Comment: @FelixKling there are such things as boolean attributes. Saying that may have any string does not mean that shall have only strings.  Instead, it means that a string value is allowed amongst other possible values (such as boolean)

Comment: @ochi: The "value" of a boolean attribute is the empty string or a string containing the name of the attribute: *"A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

**If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.**"* https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: @ochi—see the DOM 3 specification for [*setAttribute*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082): "*This value is a simple string; it is not parsed as it is being set.*"

Comment: @ochi: And again, this is the only part in the HTML spec the generic structure of attributes. Why do the mention string values explicitly, if there are other possible values? Why don't the write "may have any number value"?

Comment: I mean, I'm not denying that I could be wrong. But I don't find the arguments brought up against my interpretation  very convincing. One argument against my interpretation could be the HTML4 spec, which avoids talking about types: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: Well, again, I am only saying that **a)** There are exceptions (as quoted by the spec & you)  **b)** may have any string != strings always.

Comment: @FelixKling I believe it's implied, it's just it's not saying so explicitly. Also **@ochi** the statement *"Except where otherwise specified,"* may mean that the attribute *can not have any* string value, not that it's not a string.

Comment: @Spencer: That's how I'm interpreting it. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Anyways, I will try to reach out and see if this part can be clarified.

Comment: One final note, related to boolean attributes, *The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.* - You can 'represent' a *true* value by adding an ASCII value but it is only a representation.  The actual value is the boolean *true* or *false* - maybe it is only semantics but maybe it is one of those exceptions

Comment: For better or worse, I filed https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=28139. Lets see what happens.

Comment: @ochi—you're confused. The HTML specification is for markup, the DOM specification is for the DOM. HTML has a concept of boolean attributes (*checked*, *selected*, *disabled*) that have no value in the markup. The DOM tries to reconcile that with properties and attributes. Attributes represent actual markup values that are retrieved by *getAttribute*, so they **must** be strings. HTML can't have any other type. The problem for the DOM specification is what should *getAttribute* return for an attribute that has no value?

Comment: Ah! I see... therein lies my confusion... yet, I am only quoting Felix's own HTML spec quotation... o.0 (the question *is* about markup, right?)